# Swift for object in objects Xcode 6.3 '[AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'Generator'

Tags: swift, for-loop, xcode6.3

Xcode 6.3   '[AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'Generator'

Error from this line "for object2 in objects2{"

```
            let findImage:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
            findImage.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: self.userlist as [AnyObject])
            findImage.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (objects2:[AnyObject]?, error2:NSError?)->Void in
                //var recordProfileImg:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
                if !(error2 != nil){
                    for object2 in objects2{
                        println(objects2.count)
                        let sweet:PFObject = object2 as PFObject
                        if sweet.objectForKey("profileImage") != nil{
                            var recordProfileImg:NSMutableArray = [sweet.objectId,sweet.objectForKey("profileImage") as PFFile]
                            self.userImageList.addObject(recordProfileImg)

                            // println(userImageList)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is the link of picture.
http://imageshack.com/a/img537/3446/DzQiad.png

Answer (score 1):

Since `objects2` is an optional, you have to unwrap it. If you're sure it won't be nil, try this:

```
for object2 in objects2! {
```

Comment: And if you aren't? Trying to understand why ```if let``` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: The easiest solution would be `for object2 in objects2 ?? [] { ... }`, which will substitute an empty array if `objects2` is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Use ! after your array :

```
for info in array! {

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue after Xcode updgrade, figured it out.
First, you don't need the Types in the parameter list after latest update of XCode (something changed there).

```
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock( { (myItems, error) -> Void in
    ...
```

Second, you need to add the ! in the for loop for your list of items (in the example below *myItems!*).  So your code should be similar to this:

```
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock( { (myItems, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for item in myItems! {
                let itemToWorkWith = item as! PFObject
                ...
```